# Nginx not mapping to location

Tags: nginx, location

I am trying to access URL from the browser

```
http://example.com/validateResetPassword/?access_token=8E27UWYuamdf
```

my Nginx location mapping is:

```
    location  ~*  /validateResetPassword {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8085/$request_uri;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
```

so whenever request comes like from browser

http://example.com/validateResetPassword/?access_token=8E27UWYuam

it should redirect to my spring boot application on port 8085.
I also tried after removing ~* but nothing is working.

also, I can see below error:

> 2019/11/25 13:19:29 [info] 13780#13780: *37 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 10.68.104.173, server: 10.121.42.22:80
>
> 2019/11/25 13:19:29 [error] 13783#13783: *39 no resolver defined to resolve localhost, client: 10.68.104.173, server: mydoamin.com, request: "GET /validateResetPassword/dsfsdfsd HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
>
> 2019/11/25 13:19:30 [error] 13783#13783: *39 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: 10.68.104.173, server: uc1f-bioinfocloud-algae-dev, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "uc1f-bioinfocloud-algae-dev", referrer: "http://example.com/validateResetPassword/dsfsdfsd"

Answer (score 0):

This sounds quite critical to me:

> *39 no resolver defined to resolve localhost

Did you try changing it to `127.0.0.1`?

edit:

> it should redirect to my spring boot application on port 8085.

If you use `proxy*`, you are not about to **redirect** but doing a **subrequest** to another host...